# Fitting curves to a set of points

Tags: objective-c, ios, math, interpolation, gaussian

Basically, I have a set of up to 100 co-ordinates, along with the **desired** tangents to the curve at the first and last point.

I have looked into various methods of curve-fitting, by which I mean an algorithm with takes the inputted data points and tangents, and outputs the equation of the cure, such as the gaussian method and interpolation, but I really struggled understanding them.

I am not asking for code (If you choose to give it, thats acceptable though :) ), I am simply looking for help into this algorithm. It will eventually be converted to Objective-C for an iPhone app, if that changes anything..

**EDIT:**
I know the order of all of the points. They are not too close together, so passing through all points is necessary - aka interpolation (unless anyone can suggest something else). And as far as I know, an algebraic curve is what I'm looking for. This is all being done on a **2D** plane by the way

Comment: A lot of questions: Are you talking about *interpolation* (will go through all points) or *approximation* (may be off by some distance)? Do you want a single equation for the whole curve, or are piecewise descriptions acceptable? What kind of output curve do you need? Bezier splines, algebraic curves, or something else entirely? Do you know the order of your points along the curve? Are we talking about points in the 2D plane here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend to consider cubic splines. There is some explanation and code to calculate them in plain C in [Numerical Recipes book (chapter 3.3)](http://apps.nrbook.com/c/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

Most interpolation methods originally work with functions: given a set of *x* and *y* values, they compute a function which computes a *y* value for every *x* value, meeting the specified constraints. As a function can only ever compute a single *y* value for every *x* value, such an curve cannot loop back on itself.

To turn this into a real 2D setup, you want *two* functions which compute *x* resp. *y* values based on some parameter that is conventionally called *t*. So the first step is computing *t* values for your input data. You can usually get a good approximation by summing over euclidean distances: think about a polyline connecting all your points with straight segments. Then the parameter would be the distance along this line for every input pair.

So now you have two interpolation problem: one to compute *x* from *t* and the other *y* from *t*. You can formulate this as a [spline interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_interpolation), e.g. using cubic splines. That gives you a large system of linear equations which you can solve iteratively up to the desired precision.

The result of a spline interpolation will be a piecewise description of a suitable curve. If you wanted a single equation, then a lagrange interpolation would fit that bill, but the result might have odd twists and turns for many sets of input data.